# Chart.js – how to remove data entries from the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a simpel doughnut chart, made with the following code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Buchen (65%)", "Eschen (11%)", "Ahorn (8%)", "Eichen,  Linden und weitere Laubhölzer (11%)", "Nadelholz (5%)"],
        datasets: [
            {
                backgroundColor: ["#2F4F4F", "#008080","#2E8B57","#3CB371","#3AC9A3"],
                data: [65,11,8,11,5]
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation(),
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
            }
        }
    }
});
```

which turns into:
[image]

How to remove the '65' at the very end of the tooltip which pops up while hovering?
I came to understand that callbacks make it possible to [customize the tooltip](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/configuration/tooltip.html), however not yet managed this edit via the documentation.

Comment: Please limit your tags only to those that are actually relevant to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the way you want to see the hover over tooltips:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Buchen (65%)", "Eschen (11%)", "Ahorn (8%)", "Eichen,  Linden und weitere Laubhölzer (11%)", "Nadelholz (5%)"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: ["#2F4F4F", "#008080", "#2E8B57", "#3CB371", "#3AC9A3"],
      data: [65, 11, 8, 11, 5]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation(),
        display: true,
        position: 'right',
      },
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(context) {
            return context.label;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: just a note that may be helpful: if you console log the context object, you'll see what are the attributes that one can display (their names like to change from version to version of chart.js)

Answer (score 1):

After testing this might be the solution and also soft coded the labels. As your labels were hard coded and if the values would change it should match up automatically.

Added a video as well breaking it down: https://youtu.be/b6oVAcQijIw

```
// Created an array to soft code your values in the labels. 
const datavalue = [65,11,8,11,5];
const datalabels = ['Buchen', 'Eschen', 'Ahorn', 'Eichen, Linden und weitere Laubhölzer', 'Nadelholz'];


var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: [datalabels[0], datalabels[1] + ' (' + datavalue[1] +'%)', datalabels[2] + ' (' + datavalue[2] +'%)', datalabels[3] + ' (' + datavalue[3] +'%)', datalabels[4] + ' (' + datavalue[4] +'%)'],
        datasets: [
            {
                backgroundColor: ["#2F4F4F", "#008080","#2E8B57","#3CB371","#3AC9A3"],
                data: datavalue
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation(),
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
            },
            // For the tooltipItem is the trigger of the hover effect. 
            tooltip: {
              callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem){
                let label = myChart.data.labels[tooltipItem.dataIndex];
                let value = myChart.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.dataIndex];
                return label;
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent! The suggestion on soft coding as much as possible is very legitimate and served a great learning curve. Valuable video.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the description and I noticed you are gonna change tooltips.
Okay, I am gonna write how I solve that problem.

```
tooltips: {
            titleFontSize: 15,
            titleMarginBottom: 10,
            bodyFontSize: 15,
            bodySpacing: 5,
            xPadding: 15,
            yPadding: 10,
            enabled: false,
            callbacks: {
              label: function (context, data) {
                return parseFloat(context.value).toFixed(1);                  
              },
              title: function (context) {
                return mediaList.length;
              },
            },
            custom: function (tooltipModel) {
              let tooltipEl = document.getElementById("chartjs-tooltip");

              // Create element on first render
              if (!tooltipEl) {
                tooltipEl = document.createElement("div");
                tooltipEl.id = "chartjs-tooltip";
                tooltipEl.innerHTML = "<table></table>";
                document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
              }
              tooltipEl.classList.add("tooltip-wrapper");
              // Hide if no tooltip
              if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
                tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                return;
              }

              // Set caret Position
              tooltipEl.classList.remove("above", "below", "no-transform");
              if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
                tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
              } else {
                tooltipEl.classList.add("no-transform");
              }

              function getBody(bodyItem) {
                return bodyItem.lines;
              }

              // Set Text
              if (tooltipModel.body) {
                let titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
                let bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

                let innerHtml = "<thead>";

                titleLines.forEach(function (title) {
                  innerHtml +=
                    "<tr><th style='text-align: left'>" + title + "</th></tr>";
                });
                innerHtml += "</thead><tbody>";

                bodyLines.forEach(function (body, i) {
                  const colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
                  let style = "background:" + colors.backgroundColor;
                  style += "; border-color:" + colors.borderColor;
                  style += "; border-width: 2px";
                  style += "; width: 15px";
                  style += "; height: 15px";
                  style += "; display: inline-block";
                  style += "; margin: 0px 5px";
                  style += "; border-radius: 50%";
                  let span = '<span style="' + style + '"></span>';
                  innerHtml +=
                    "<tr><td style='display: flex;align-items: center'>" +
                    parseFloat(body[0].split(":")[1]).toFixed(1) +
                    "%" +
                    span +
                    body[0].split(":")[0] +
                    "</td></tr>";
                });
                innerHtml += "</tbody>";

                var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector("table");
                tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
              }

              // `this` will be the overall tooltip
              const position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

              // Display, position, and set styles for font
              tooltipEl.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(45 54 89 / 75%)";
              tooltipEl.style.color = "white";
              tooltipEl.style.borderRadius = "6px";
              tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
              tooltipEl.style.position = "absolute";
              tooltipEl.style.width = "max-content";
              tooltipEl.style.transform = "translate(-106%, -50%)";
              tooltipEl.style.left =
                position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + "px";
              tooltipEl.style.top =
                position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + "px";
              tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltipModel._bodyFontFamily;
              tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltipModel.bodyFontSize + "px";
              tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltipModel._bodyFontStyle;
              tooltipEl.style.padding =
                tooltipModel.yPadding + "px " + tooltipModel.xPadding + "px";
              tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = "none";
            },
          },
```

As you can see here, you should create a custom tooltip in the tooltip option.

Answer (score -1):

Under Tooltip Callbacks there is a reference to modifying the tooltip label: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback

I think you need to add something like this:

```
    options: {
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(context) {
                        var newLabel = context.label || '';
                        var lastIndexOfSpace = newLabel.lastIndexOf(' ');
                        if (lastIndexOfSpace > 0) {
                            newLabel = newLabel.substring(0, lastIndexOfSpace);
                        }
                        return newLabel;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doest work when there are multiple spaces in there, also returns the label of the dataset and not the label of where the data is linked to: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/tgfkph8x/2/

Comment: You're right. My answer also incorrectly assumes that context.label contains all of the text in the label; that is not the case. For whatever reason context.label only contains the first bit of text in OP's question. Fiddle with my answer: https://jsfiddle.net/ot0uk6sn/18/